# How to do 'out' in a Func<T> in c#

Tags: c#

I am using a library which measure metrics for running code.
The usage of the library is something like this.

```
_Library.Wrap("AnyStringForMetrics", Func<T>);
```

So whatever I pass into the Func as a lambda will be measured and result of it will be returned.

At the moment, I have method where I want to measure this line where it tries to create or get a user with that id. (newlyCreated will be true if the user was created)

```
public User GetOrCreate(long id, out bool newlyCreated) {
    // some random checks
    return UserDatabase.GetOrCreate(id, out newlyCreated);
}
```

But now, if I try to wrap my code around

```
public User GetOrCreate(long id, out bool newlyCreated) {
    // some random checks
    return _Library.Wrap(
        "UserGetOrCreate", () => UserDatabase.GetOrCreate(id, out newlyCreated));
}
```

I will get an exception for using "out" inside lambda expression. How should I resolve this?

If possible please write out a concrete code example... Thanks.

Comment: Use a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) as return type instead.
`public (User user, bool newlyCreated) GetOrCreate(long id) {
    var user = ....;
    bool created = ....;
    return (user, created);
}`

and map it to `Func<(User, bool)>`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes could you put in an answer? I think this might work. I can accept.

Comment: nvm looks like they decided this question is duplicate so cannot answer. I tried your method it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) as return type instead and thus avoid using an `out` parameter.

```cs
public (User user, bool newlyCreated) GetOrCreate(long id) {
    var user = ....;
    bool created = ....;
    return (user, created);
}
```

and map it to `Func<(User, bool)>`.